# VBA - Enter array into multiline textbox on userform

Tags: vba, userform

I want to enter each element of an array onto a new line in multiline textbox on a userform. I have the Multiline and EnterKeyBehaviour of the textbox set to True.

The code below will enter the array elements but after entered they are then overwritten by the next element.

```
For i = LBound(clipArray) To UBound(clipArray)
        frmMyForm.txtBox.Text = clipArray(i)
Next
```

I have tried variations like below (with vbCr, vbCrLf etc) but still does not work.

```
frmMyForm.txtBox.Text = clipArray(i, vbNewLine)
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use:

```
   frmMyForm.txtBox.Text = Join(clipArray, vbLf)
```